Resolving : virt-customize: warning: random seed could not be set for this type of guest
To resolve this issue, you can create a random seed in the disk image using this commands :
debian : sudo apt-get install libguestfs-tools
mkdir -p /mnt/test
guestmount -a disk-image.img -i --rw /mnt/test
cd /mnt/test/var/lib/systemd/
dd if=/dev/urandom of=random-seed bs=512 count=4
chmod 755 random-seed
guestunmount /mnt/test/

after that, running commands like : sudo virt-customize -a kinetic-server-cloudimg-amd64.img --install qemu-guest-agent should no more report the warning : virt-customize: warning: random seed could not be set for this type of guest
trying to install qemu-guest-agent ont ubuntu 24.04 cloudinit image
